Merging Excel Spread Sheets for YTD compensation
I have everyone's commission payouts by quarter in separate excel sheets. I want to create 1 consolidated spreadsheet that shows everyone's YTD commission payout. How can I do that in the easiest way?

What research have you done and what have you tried? there are questions on this site regarding merging spreadsheets already: I recommend you begin by at least reviewing the other questions regarding this.

Does this answer your question? Merge two Excel sheets

Copy and paste the payout from 1 sheet to the other sheet?

You may use Excel Power Query, then combine queries: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-and-join-tables-cbd17828-7a50-4dc6-9aac-20af4ef6d8a6
